# How to print this series x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+...(x^n/n!) in C?

Tags: c

I wish to write a program which calculates the series *x - x<sup>3</sup>/3! + x<sup>5</sup>/5! - x<sup>7</sup>/7! + ... + (-1)<sup>(n-1)/2</sup>.x<sup>n</sup>/n!* by taking `x` and `n` as user inputs.

This is what I have tried, and well there is no output when I enter the values for `x` and `n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <process.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double series(int, int);
double factorial(int);

int main()
{
    double x, n, res;
    printf("This program will evaluate the following series:\nx-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+...(x^n/n!)\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter a value for x and an odd value for n\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &n);
    /*if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive value!\n");
        exit(0);
    }*/
    res = series(x, n);
    printf("For the values you've entered, the value of the series is:\n %lf", res);
}

double series(int s, int t)
{
    int i, sign = 1;
    double r, fact, exec;

    for (i = 1; i <= t; i + 2)
    {
        exec = sign * (pow(s, i) / factorial(i));
        r += exec;
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return r;
}

double factorial(int p)
{
    double f = 1.0;
    while (p > 0)
    {
        f *= p;
        p--;
    }
    return f;
}
```

When I enter values for `x` and `n`, it simply shows nothing.
While I've written in C, C++ solutions are also appreciated.

[image: Output window in code::blocks]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: use `i=i+2` instead of `i+2`

Comment: Don't post text as images!

Comment: We,, you can't! Becaused there is no language "C/C++", only the two **different** languages C and C++. Your code seems to be C, so why spamming tags?

Comment: @Olaf last sentence of the question: "While I've written in C, C++ solutions are also appreciated."

Comment: @Bob__: Still there is no "C/C++". The code is clearly C, not C++ and ansking for debugging help. If this is a request for code, it is OT anyway.

Comment: You don't need to keep working out the power and the factorial from scratch, since each term can be derived from the previous term. For example `t3 = t2 * sign * x**2 / (4*5);` (using the double ** to mean power).

Comment: @WeatherVane - you could have written `x * x` rather than inventing a "power" operator!  `t3 = -t2 * x * x / 4 / 5`.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, I can't think why I did it like that. (PS I didn't invent it :)

Answer (score 4):

The loop

```
for(i=1;i<=t;i+2)
```

in the function `series()` is an infinite loop when `t >= 1` because `i` isn't updated in the loop. Try changing `+` to `+=` and use

```
for(i=1;i<=t;i+=2)
```

instead. Also it seems you should use type `int` for `x` and `n` in the function `main()` because the arguments of `series()` is `int`. Don't forget to change the format specifier when changing their types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who helped. Here's the final working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double series(int,int);
double factorial(int);

int main()
{
    int x,n; double res;
    printf("This program will evaluate the following series:\nx-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+...(x^n/n!)\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter a value for x and an odd value for n\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&n);
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        n=n-1;
    }
    res=series(x,n);
    printf("For the values you've entered, the value of the series is:\n%lf",res);
}

double series(int s, int t)
{
    int i,sign=1; double r=0.0,fact,exec;
    for(i=1;i<=t;i+=2)
    {
        exec=sign*(pow(s,i)/factorial(i));
        r+=exec;
        sign*=-1;
    }
    return r;
}

double factorial(int p)
{
    double f=1;
    while(p>0)
    {
        f*=p;
        p--;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in loop we step by two for getting odd numbers.by multiplying the current temp variable by the previous temp variable in the loop with neccesary terms like x square and dividing by i*(i-1) i.e for factorial and multiply with -1 i.e to achive negavtive number alternatively. by using this temp variable and adding it to sum variable in every iteration will give us answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, x;
    cout << "enter x and no.of terms: ";
    cin >> x >> n;
    float sum = 0, temp = x;
    for (int i = 3; i < 2 * n + 2; i = i + 2)
    {
        temp = ((-1 * temp) *(x*x)) / i*(i-1);
        sum = sum + temp;   
    }
cout << x + sum;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// series x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+...(x^n/n!)   

#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>  

double factorial (int);
double calc (float, float);

int 
main () 
{ 
int x, deg;      
double fin;    
printf ("x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!)-(x^7/7!)+...(x^n/n!)\n");      
printf ("Enter value of x\n");      
scanf ("%d", &x);      
printf ("highest degree in denom i.e., 1 or 3 or 5 whatever, it should be odd .\n");
      scanf ("%d", &deg);
  fin = calc (x, deg);   
printf ("the summation of series =%1f\n", fin);
      return 0;
    }

  double calc (float num, float res) 
{
      int count, sign = 1;
      double rres = 0;
      for (count = 1; count <= res; count += 2)        
    {
          rres += sign * (pow (num, count) / factorial (count));
          sign *= -1;
        }
      return (rres);
    }
       double factorial (int num) 
{      
int count;      
double sum = 1;      
for (count = 1; count <= num; count++)        
    {
          sum *= count;
        }
     return (sum);
 }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are somewhat *poor* ones. You may want to add an explanation for your code or some summary of what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Write a program to obtain the sum of the n terms (n and x to be taken from the user) of the
   following series x – x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! ...........................................
 */
public class Ass1Q10 {
    
    static int fact(int n) {
        int fact=1;
        for(int i=n; i>0;i--) {
            fact*=i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n,x,sign=1;
        double sum=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of terms upto you want the sum :");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter the value of X: ");
        x=sc.nextInt();
        
        for (int i=1; i<=(2*n)-1; i++) {
            double temp=0;
            temp = (Math.pow(x, i))/fact(i);
            sum+=(temp*sign);
            sign = -sign;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is :"+ sum);
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [answer].